# Why do huge wallets often have repeated tiny (< $1) transactions?

Tags: dust

Looking around at some so-called 'whales' on the BTC richlist (as well as other currencies) I see it is quite common a *huge* wallet is regularly making miniscule transactions as low as a few cents.

Just the one I had open:
https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin/address/3LYJfcfHPXYJreMsASk2jkn69LWEYKzexb

[image]

In this case the 0.00000547 value comes up many times. What does it signify when wallets have these sort of micro-transactions?